# Spring-boot Couchbase filter by attribute throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

When I am trying to read entire bucket by `findAll(Pageable)` works fine.
When I try to filter paged read - findByUserId (find by userId) - getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
filtering documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)

Entity:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public String id;

    @Field
    public String userId;

    @Field
    public String description;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Event, String> {
    Page<Event> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable page);
}
```

Indexes:
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `#primary` ON `event`
CREATE INDEX `userId` ON `event`(`userId`) WHERE (`_class` = "com.example.demo.Event")

Libraries:
Spring Boot: 2.3.4
spring-data-couchbase: 4.0.4

Getting following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source emitted more than one item
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onNext(MonoSingle.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.subscribe(EmitterProcessor.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:188) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.Reactor$SilentMonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(Reactor.java:178) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[na:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.succeed(BaseRequest.java:143) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.completeInitialResponse(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:251) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.handleHttpContent(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:238) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.channelRead(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:187) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:381) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:211) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:289) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.ExecutableFindByQueryOperationSupport$ExecutableFindByQuerySupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindByQueryOperationSupport.java:60) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.N1qlRepositoryQueryExecutor.execute(N1qlRepositoryQueryExecutor.java:74) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.CouchbaseRepositoryQuery.execute(CouchbaseRepositoryQuery.java:42) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findByUserId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findByUserId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.demo.EventService.findByUserId(EventService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

Long answer short:

spring-data-couchbase v4.0.4 is still under development. Some of functionalities are broken. [github ongoing work](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/pull/261)
Spring boot 2.3 uses spring-boot-couchbase v4.0 and has issues. [JHipster Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/jhipster-dev/c/P_4c1bCMVtI/m/ZE--g7qYBwAJ?pli=1)

Solution:
Downgrade to older version of spring boot. I downgraded spring-boot from 2.3.4 to 2.2.2